# AX 2012 - MorphX Report issue

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

I have a MorphX report (AOT report) that has been imported from 3.0. The problem is the class that starts the report is based off of RunBaseReport.  It then sends in parameters from the dialog box.  This all works client side.  I want this to run on the batch server and schedule it to print out reports and email them.

The issue is in the init method.  Where SalesReport is the above mentioned class that overrides RunBaseReport:

```
SalesReport = element.args().caller();
```

This line doesn't work when coming from the batch server.  So then when I try to call `SalesReport.parmDate()` I get an

> this object has not been initialized

error.  Can this not be done from a batch server anymore or what are alternatives?

Comment: Is this a custom report in AX 3.0? You could try to move the line to the main method of the class and save all parameters that you need using the `#CurrentList` macro. But I would recommend to reimplement the report as SSRS report.

Comment: Yes completely custom report.  I agree with your recommendation on reimplimenting but that is not my call so it's not an option on the table right now.  I'm not sure what you mean by moving the line, is there an example I can see?

Comment: You need to implement the pack/unpack pattern, the batch server does not run a client in 2012 as it does in 3. This will save your parameters for the batch job to use. Bight the bullet and rewrite, I'm not sure how that wouldn't be your call.

Comment: There is a pack/unpack pattern.  I've actually sent this issue off to Microsoft as it loses the caller value when ran on the server (batch).  I trace it beyond the method that allows it to lose the value but running this RunBaseReport on batch with pack/unpack implemented it loses the caller value.